# setContentView crashes android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es, renderer

I am going through the android tutorials on how to use graphics and animations. When I set my new content view the application crashes. I looked up the problem here and saw people with similar problems with this tutorial, but none of the solutions I have found have worked for me. I know people said the order of the lines when you set up your renderer is important but I have it in the same order they said to use. When I run in debug it seems to crash in the middle of the call to setContentView (which I can't see into, eclipse just says sorce not found at this part since I didn't write it).

Here is my main activity file:
package com.example.graphicsretry;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        /*mGLView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        MyGL20Renderer mg = new MyGL20Renderer();
        mGLView.setRenderer(mg);*/
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }

}

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        MyGL20Renderer mg = new MyGL20Renderer();
        setRenderer(mg);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}
```

This is my renderer class

```
package com.example.graphicsretry;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;

public class MyGL20Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

Here is my android manifest file. It has the uses-feature tag needed and two support texture tags (NOTE: I tried it without the support texture tags and it still crashed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.graphicsretry"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.graphicsretry.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I pasted my logcat file here in case it helps anyone:
http://pastebin.com/EvB9NYJF

Comment: can you please paste the short message of logcat that have crash info only

Comment: How do I get only the short message? I'm sorry for not knowing.

Comment: when you got Exception crash then see the Logcat.
there are statement like exception, caused by in red lines 
so these are related to crash

Comment: I found someone that had an actual android device to run it on, and it worked on there. It turns out that it was just an issue with running it on the emulator. Supposedly there is an emulator setting to allow OpenGL-es to run or not. I still need to find the setting, but I'm glad to know what the problem was. Hopefully other people won't get stuck on the same thing now.